# How to read a .war file?

Tags: files, compression

I am trying to view the content of a .war file. I first did set its permissions with `chmod 777` then when I try to accces it using:

```
cd /usr/local/standalone/deployments/Sample.war/WEB-INF/classes/
```

It is giving `cd: /usr/local/standalone/deployments/Sample.war/WEB-INF/classes/: Not a directory` and I am not able to proceed further.

Can someone help me in this issue?

Comment: Don't use `chmod 777` on a compressed file. You don't need execution bit for reading it. A safe `644` or `640` is recommended.

Comment: See the official Java docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html

Comment: Is `/usr/local/standalone/deployments/Sample.war` a directory or a file ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

.war files are packed.  You can extract the information by using either of the following commands:

```
jar -xvf Sample.war
unzip Sample.war
```

You should then be able to run `cd /usr/local/standalone/deployments/Sample.war/WEB-INF/classes/`

Comment: `jar -xvf *war` won't work if there is more than one war file in the current directory. `tar -xvfz` won't work at all, you are confusing gzipped files and zipped ones.

Comment: This is true, I didn't mean to infer that it would work with multiple wars, just that you could use that command verbatim for any one war.  I've changed it

Comment: I think it's better to use `jar -tvf` and not the proposed `jar -xvf` way. So files aren't extracted (and contaminate your .) but just listed.

Answer (score 8):

`.war` files are zipped archives.

You can list what they contain with either

```
jar tvf Sample.war
```

or

```
zipinfo Sample.war
```

Should you want to see the content of files stored in an archive, you need to first extract it somewhere:

```
mkdir /tmp/foo
cd /tmp/foo
unzip /usr/local/standalone/deployments/Sample.war
ls -l WEB-INF/classes/
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to extract the file you can use `vim filename.war` to read the contents of the file. You can read subdirectories of files by selecting them and pressing enter.

Comment: For this to work, you need the package `unzip` installed.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to extract the war file `jar xvf Sample.war`. Then you can cd in to the war file.

Answer (score 1):

If the unix commands does not work, ftp the file to local machine.

`.jar` or `.war` or `.ear` any archive file can be opened in 7-Zip by following the steps below -

1. Right click the archive file
2. 7-Zip
3. Open archive

You should be able to see all the archive file contents. Now browse through the folder/file and then right click -> edit the file -> save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Besides extracting them with jar or unzip, you can also use the Midnight Commander (mc) and navigate to these files and press Enter on them as if they were directories.

If this doesn't immediately work, your flavour of mc is not configured to know the .war suffix, but you can still use this feature by typing either
    cd Sample.war#uzip
(old mc) or
    cd Sample.war/uzip://
(mc in Debian unstable) and pressing Enter. As an added benefit, pressing Escape then Enter (in some terminals, also Alt-Enter but this is not portable so don’t depend on it) inserts the current filename into the command line, but you’ll have to press Backspace too because it adds a space, and the #uzip or /uzip:// needs to immediately follow the filename.

This is known as the mc VFS (virtual filesystem).

I won’t repeat the unzip/fastjar/jar answers here, but they’re also correct.